# I am using fetch to make an api call that is not working in "Mozilla Firefox Version 17.0"

Tags: javascript, xhtml, fetch-api

Hi I Have a problem with my Javascript code. I am making a API call using fetch. And i am showing the response in my map. It works perfect in all browsers but it do not work in "Mozilla Firefox Version 17.0". I want to use it in this version what solution i can find for this version of browser.

```
           fetch('https://xzy.example.api)
           .then(function(response) {
                   return response.json();
           })
```

Comment: Its probably [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility) neither are promises

Comment: you can go and find a fetch polyfill like [this one](https://github.com/github/fetch).

Comment: Firefox 17 is almost 7 years old and is no longer supported by Mozilla.

Comment: Can you explain what reason you have for needing to support this particular version? I'm curious!

Comment: Because the PDF Plugins @MrLister

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` was [introduced in Firefox 39.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility) MDN links to [this polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch).

It is not natively supported in Firefox 17 (which you should not use as it is ancient ([release date: November 20, 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Firefox_17_through_23)) and many years behind the latest security updates).

Comment: I know but i need to use this last version.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch is [not-supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility) in the version of FireFox 17

Comment: I know but i need to use this last version.